# mysql create table with foreign keys failing

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a tables in a db that have foreign keys. what am i missing?

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userName` varchar(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`password` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`firstName` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`lastName` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `topLevelPermissions` (
`id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userId` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`user` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`group` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`someField` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`someOtherField` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES users (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and i see nothing related to foreign keys.  in fact when i

```
show create table topLevelPermissions;
```

i see

```
 CREATE TABLE `topLevelPermissions` (
 `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userId` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`user` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`group` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`someField` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`someOtherField` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `userId` (`userId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Innodb only supports foreign key constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Innodb only supports foreign key constraints. So switch to Innodb if you want to utilize foreign key constraints.